# Unable to record from microphone on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am trying to use `pyaudio` to stream input from the microphone on M1 MacBookPro, but getting `OSErrors`. Here is the code to list different microphones,

```py
    def list_microphones(pyaudio_instance):
        info = pyaudio_instance.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
        numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')

        result = []
        for i in range(0, numdevices):
            if (pyaudio_instance.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
                name = pyaudio_instance.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(
                    0, i).get('name')
                result += [[i, name]]
        return result
```

On running this I get two microphone (external and inbuilt) -- `[[0, 'External Microphone'], [2, 'MacBook Pro Microphone']]`. I have tried both options,

#### Microphone 1 or 2: Internal -- Error is `OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error`

##### Code

```py
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
FRAME_DURATION = 30
CHUNK = int(RATE * FRAME_DURATION / 1000)
RECORD_SECONDS = 50

#
stream = audio.open(input_device_index=2, # or 0
                format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
```

##### Error

```bash
||PaMacCore (AUHAL)|| AUHAL component not found.Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/op_asr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/op_asr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "live-whisper-asr.py", line 61, in vad_process
    stream = audio.open(input_device_index=2,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/op_asr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 754, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/op_asr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 445, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with python from iTerm "Terminal" and grant access to microphone if your're asked for. The specific python interpreter you ran should have now access to audio hardware. Did work with pyenv, but didnt find a way to grant rights to conda environments. I you clicked "no" to microphone access, you won't be asked again for that. Apples security drives me nuts as a developer.